# DIV tags moving when moving other DIV tags

Tags: asp.net, css, html

The problem I am getting is that when i am moving a DIV tag another DIV tag is automatically moving aswell which is what i don't want.

This is an image of what is on my screen now:

[image]

**The Labels, Textboxes is inside 1 DIV tag, The box image is the background of another DIV tag and the button has another DIV tag.**

**This is my HTML code of this:**

```
<div id="LoginBox" style="background-image: url(Image/LoginBox_v2.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; height: 500px; width: 500px;">

        <div id="Information">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Username" runat="server" Text="Username:"/>
            <br />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Username"/> 
            <br />
            <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Password" runat="server" Text="Password:" />
            <br />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Password" TextMode="Password" />

     <div id="container">
        <a href="bHomePage.aspx" class="button" id="buttonlogin">
            Login
            <span class="icons button" />
        </a>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**I want to be able to move the `Information` DIV tag down inside the box in a good position, but when i try and set the CSS the other DIV tag `LoginBox` moves down aswell?**

**Here is my CSS of all the DIV tags at the moment:**

```
#LoginBox {
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 0%;

}

#Information {
margin-left: 0%;
margin-top: 0%;
height: 460px;
}

#container {
margin-left: 0%;
width: 125px; 
}
```

Some of the CSS show 0% because i moved back to 0% when it didn't work. I have also tried moving all the objects separate but that didn't work either?

Comment: Don't use `<br>` tags for layout. Using blocks, margins & padding would be a good place to start.

Comment: and i think there is a closing div tag missing. dont know, if this is a problem here, but still...

Comment: Please put your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok thanks taken into account and will sort out that, do you have any ideas of a solutions to my issue?

Comment: @Homungus Sorry i just missed a DIV out when copying and pasting it is there my bad.

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya What is this website, i don't understand what it is used for?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a JSfiddle.net example with your HTML & CSS so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok never used this website before ill post link now.

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya http://jsfiddle.net/by5aZ/

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/by5aZ/

Comment: We can't use ASP...you'd have to use the output HTML

Comment: @Paulie_D How do i do this?

Comment: Footer Position Changes. used position:relative; @user3129331

Comment: Give me  website url @user3129331

Answer (score 1):

Try adding
     overflow: auto;
into your parent div which is LoginBox on your code.

also its better to mention full code here. because there are 3 dives opened but only 2 closed. hope you have other one closed some ware down.
gl!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, i eventually managed to figure it out after 3 days, thanks.